# Why did not update table values with validation in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

in laravel 5.6 app I have table name as vehicles, then I need update some of table values in VehicleController update function with validation as this,

```
 $this->validate($request, [
            'provincename'     => 'required|min:3',
            'districtname'    => 'required',
            'townname'    => 'required',
            'brandname'    => 'required',
            'modelname'    => 'required',
            'year'    => 'required',
            'condition'    => 'required',
            'milage'    => 'required',
            'data'    => 'required',
            'price'    => 'required',
            'telephone'    => 'required',
            'categoryname'    => 'required',
            'tramsmission'    => 'required',
            'fueltype'    => 'required',
            'enginecapacity'   => 'required'
         ]);
```

and my update controller is like this,

```
 $vehicle = Vehicle::find($id);

        $vehicle->provincename = $request->input('provincename');
        $vehicle->districtname = $request->input('districtname');
        $vehicle->townname = $request->input('townname');
        $vehicle->brandname = $request->input('brandname');
        $vehicle->modelname = $request->input('modelname');
        $vehicle->modelyear = $request->input('year');
        $vehicle->condition = $request->input('condition');
        $vehicle->milage = $request->input('milage');
        $vehicle->detail = $request->input('data');
        $vehicle->price = $request->input('price');
        $vehicle->telephone = $request->input('telephone');
        $vehicle->categoryname =  $request->input('categoryname');
        $vehicle->transmission = $request->input('transmission');
        $vehicle->fueltype = $request->input('fueltype');
        $vehicle->enginecapacity = $request->input('enginecapacity');
        $vehicle->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

        $vehicle->save();
```

My update is ok. it is working. but with controller validation it is not updating. without validation it is working. how can fix this? what is the problem with this?

Comment: Maybe the data you're passing in isn't valid according to the rules you've given?

Comment: I validate only input request no any rules

Comment: Try this on your blade and see what it renders 

`@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
`

Answer (score 0):

try this kind of validation format:

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'provincename'     => 'required|min:3',
    'districtname'    => 'required',
    'townname'    => 'required',
    'brandname'    => 'required',
    'modelname'    => 'required',
    'year'    => 'required',
    'condition'    => 'required',
    'milage'    => 'required',
    'data'    => 'required',
    'price'    => 'required',
    'telephone'    => 'required',
    'categoryname'    => 'required',
    'tramsmission'    => 'required',
    'fueltype'    => 'required',
    'enginecapacity'   => 'required'
]);
```

**EDIT**

don't forget to use the validator. Add `use Validator;` after the `namespace`.

Comment: occured this error msg **1/1) BadMethodCallException

Method validate does not exist.**

Comment: use the validor of laravel: `use Validator;` add it after the `namespace`

Comment: Teemo traveling from the League? Lol

Comment: yeah. then I found a pokemon. I'm gonna catch you.

Comment: This answer and the OP's code does exactly the same, its just written differently. Laravel controllers include validation as a trait, that is why when you extend controller you can use `$this->validate` , `$request->validate(` does the same just more steps as you also need to include validate. please read up here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation